# prepend, fade in and fade out combining

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with specified class. On button click, validates some stuff and gives user some response.

When button is clicked first time it works fine. Every next click not works so well.

```
$(".hold").prepend($('<h3>Please insert name and comment</h3>').fadeIn('fast', function () {
            $(".hold").fadeOut('slow');
    }));
```

some help ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like:

```
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $(".hold").on("click",function(){
         $(this).prepend("<h3 class='added' style='display:none;'>Please insert name and comment</h3>");
         $(".added:last-of-type").fadeIn("fast");
         $(this).fadeOut("slow");
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: hold exist as div. In that div prepends content. Content depends of user input.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand you comment.

Comment: Have this : 
('.save-new-comment').click(function (e) {
//some user validation 
//then my code for handling user input (from my post)

hope its clear now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".hold").attr("style","display:block");
        $(".hold").prepend($('<h3>Please insert name and comment</h3>').fadeIn("slow"));
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".hold").fadeOut("slow");
            $(".hold").html('');
        }, 1500);
```

Actually i needed setTimeout function.